# Register classes but don't initialise them

Tags: swift

I would like to create a manager in Swift that has registered vehicles (that can be added from outside) that get initialised depending on what string/URN is given. These classes should all have their own initializer.

Example: the Manager has a run method which takes the URN: `"urn:car:1234"`. Which should return the car class which was registered on the manager before. Another URN could be `"urn:bus:42"` which then would return a bus each with their own init. The car would have an `init(seats: Int)`, the bus could have an `init(shouldStop: Bool)`.

I tried to store the types of the classes but I don't know how I would be able to call different initializers for each class that should be run.

Here is the code so far (reduced to the minimum):

```
class VehicleManager {
   var registeredVehicles = [Vehicles.Type]()

   func run(for urn: URN) throws -> Vehicle {
        let vehicleType = try vehicleType(for: urn) // gives the Vehicle.Type from the array above.
        return vehicleType.init([different parameters]) // call different inits for each vehicle here. Make s switch over the vehicleType if necessary.
    }
}

// All vehicles implement this protocol.
protocol Vehicle {
    static var vehicleType: VerhicleType { get }

    func start()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var registeredVehicles = [Vehicle]()`? You would need to create classes or struct that conform to Vehicle to put in that array.

Comment: I think that you want subclasses for each type of vehicle, each would have their own init.

Comment: Just curious: what problem are you trying to solve by having an array or types instead of an array of, say, enum cases? You're not building a DI framework as far as I can see.

Comment: What is `[different parameters]`? Do you dynamically generate an array of `Any`s containing the parameters to be passed to the initialiser?

Comment: Basically I just want to avoid putting an instantiated object into the array and rather use the type and then do the initialisation if needed.

Comment: @adamjansch putting objects into the array is the thing I want to avoid.

Comment: @johnelemans I don't think subclasses would work here because I would have no reference to that class.

Comment: @Sweeper [different parameters] was supposed to show that I need different inits for different Types. Like in the example the car has the seats of type Int, the bus has an constructor with the parameter shouldStop of type Bool.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and thought, appreciate it!

Comment: @VadimBelyaev that may be a good idea. Using Enums with associated values instead of types could be a solution. I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with factories:

```
protocol VehicleFactory {
    associatedtype V: Vehicle
    func make(for urn: URL) -> V
}
protocol Vehicle {
    func start()
}
class VehicleManager {
    var factories = [String: any VehicleFactory]()

    func run(for urn: URL) throws -> Vehicle {
        guard let factory = try vehicleFactory(for: urn) else { throw "No such factory" }
        return factory.make(for: urn)
    }

    func vehicleFactory(for urn: URL) throws -> (any VehicleFactory)? {
        let type: String = "\(try vehicleType(for: urn))"
        return factories[type]
    }

    func vehicleType(for urn: URL) throws -> Vehicle.Type {
        // TODO urn -> Type
        return MyVehicle.self
    }
}

extension String: Error {}

// EXAMPLE

enum VerhicleType {
    case one
}

class MyVehicle: Vehicle {
    func start() {}
}

class MyVehicleFactory: VehicleFactory {
    func make(for urn: URL) -> MyVehicle {
        MyVehicle()
    }
}

func example() {
    let manager = VehicleManager()
    manager.factories["\(MyVehicle.Type.self)"] = MyVehicleFactory()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a factory with generics (very similar to your approach) instead of a whole array with already registered vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Add `init()` method into the protocol:

```
class VehicleManager {
    var registeredVehicles = [Vehicle.Type]()

    func run(for urn: URL) throws -> Vehicle {
        let vehicleType = try vehicleType(for: urn)
        return vehicleType.init(["different": "parameters"]) // call different inits for each vehicle here. Make s switch over the vehicleType if necessary.
    }

    func vehicleType(for urn: URL) throws -> Vehicle.Type {
        // gives the Vehicle.Type from the array above.
        return MyVehicle.self
    }
}

// All vehicles implement this protocol.
protocol Vehicle {
    static var vehicleType: VerhicleType { get }
    init(_ parameters: [String: Any])
    func start()
}

enum VerhicleType {
    case one
}

class MyVehicle: Vehicle {
    static var vehicleType: VerhicleType = .one
    required init(_ parameters: [String : Any]) {}
    func start() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding an init-Method is certainly not problem and having a dictionary as a parameter should work. Just not the most elegant way to deal with this.

Comment: @palme dictionary was just an example to compile the code. You didn't provide the exact API you needed (just mentioned as follows `[different parameters]`).

Comment: It's better to have a factory protocol and register factories for each type. Then use a factory for a given type to render the object.